# Flash Pro CS6: Publishing for iOS using AIR - "Could not access digital certificate"

Tags: ios, flash, air, flash-cs6

I'm following [this](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html) tutorial to publish for iOS using Flash Pro CS6. I'm using the sample files provided with that tutorial. Everything works up until I go to publish for iOS. When I click publish I get the message "Could not access digital certificate, could not load keystore file (password may be incorrect)"

This makes me think I'm entering the wrong password. Is the password needed the one associated with my Apple Developer account? Because this is the one I'm entering. If it isn't, and it's another password that's just for the certificate, that's the issue.

I created the certificate on a Windows machine using [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-8000.html) tutorial. Then converted it to a .p12 file (that Flash Pro needs) using [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html) tutorial. The only time I was promoted about a password was when I exported the .cer file to a .p12 using command prompt. I was asked to enter export password, but when I typed, it didn't enter into the command line. The export was done anyway and so I didn't think the password was necessary and the tutorial I followed didn't mention it, it was just the end of the tutorial, so I closed command prompt.

After some reading online though, I've read that when you create a certificate on a Mac using KeyChain, you set a password. But during my creation of the certificate I didn't set one. I've tried leaving the password field in Flash Pro blank but you can't, it gives a message saying "Please type password"

So, what password is the password field under where you add your certificate asking for? The one associated with your Apple Developer account or another one?

This is really confusing me and I'm surprised I haven't found more with Google or found other people asking this.

Thank you for the help.

UPDATE: I didn't know when command prompt asks for a password, it doesn't show any of the typing at all, not even stars. So I just assumed it wasn't letting me type anything. Thanks Paul! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Certificate you need is from Apple. When you sign up as a Developer you can request a code signing certificate.

More about Code-Signing Certificates:

[Maintaining Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Quote:

> All iOS apps and most Mac apps must be code signed and provisioned to
>   launch on a device, to be distributed for testing, or to be submitted
>   to the store.

On how to request your Certificate if you are enrolled as a Dev see the Caption "Requesting Signing Identities" in the link above.

Update:

The password requested in Flash Pro is the Password set via the `openssl` command.

The source of the confusion was that the openssl console does not show the export password while typing it in the command prompt.

This is expected behaviour, just enter the password blind and press Enter when you are finished. Then use the password in Flash to import.

Comment: Yeah, using the Apple Developer site, I generated a .cer certificate. But Flash Pro requires a .p12 file and so you have to export it to that format. What I don't know is: what password is it asking for?

Comment: How do I do that though? When I exported the certificate using command prompt, I was asked after the export had done: "Enter export password:" but I couldn't type anything other than press enter.

Comment: i guess you have to try to convert it again und make the command prompt work, how do you run it? from cmd?

Comment: Tried again. Can't enter anything when asked to enter export password. The export is already done when this is asked anyway. I do it following this tutorial: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html

Comment: hmm that is strange, try importing it into the windows certificate store and exporting it with a password

Comment: Could you explain this a little more. I don't what the windows certificate store is. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Join the chat then we can work it out: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63374/ios-cert

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message using the wrong `password` in the  `use an iOS certificate (.p12)`  section in the  `AIR for iOS Settings`  `Deployment` tab.